# Material-UI v15 TypeScript Definitions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, definitelytyped, definitions

Has anyone started creating a Material-UI v15 TypeScript definition file yet? I'm needing it for a project I'm currently working and I'm new to TypeScript to know if the modified file that I started is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

If someone did it would be here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/material-ui/material-ui.d.ts

Since its not, you can request it here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3ADefinition%3ARequest